# dask.bag, how should I efficiently run several computations over the same data

Tags: dask

I'm processing a fair amount of data, and the bulk of the time is spent loading the data and parsing the json/whatever. I'd like to collect simple statistics over the whole dataset using a single scan.

I'd hoped I could use the graph simplification in compute using the following pattern:

```
parsed = read_text(files).map(parsing)
example_stat_future = parsed.map(foo).frequencies()
another_stat_future = parsed.map(bar).sum()
etc.
example_stat, another_stat = compute(example_stat_future, another_stat_future)
```

but I see extreme slowdowns when trying that. Here's my example code:

```
from json import loads, dumps
from time import time
import dask.bag as db

print("Setup some dummy data")
for partition in range(10):
    with open("/tmp/issue.%d.jsonl" % partition, "w") as f_out:
        for i in range(100000):
            f_out.write(dumps({"val": i, "doubleval": i * 2}) + "\n")


print("Running as distinct computations")
loaded = db.read_text("/tmp/issue.*.jsonl").map(loads)
first_val = loaded.pluck("val").sum()
second_val = loaded.pluck("doubleval").sum()
start = time()
first_val.compute()
print("First value", time() - start)
start = time()
second_val.compute()
print("Second value", time() - start)


print("Running as a single computation")
loaded = db.read_text("/tmp/issue.*.jsonl").map(loads)
first_val = loaded.pluck("val").sum()
second_val = loaded.pluck("doubleval").sum()
start = time()
db.compute(first_val, second_val)
print("Both values", time() - start)
```

And the output

On datasets with millions of items, I've never finished a run before killing it for taking too long.

```
Setup some dummy data
Running as distinct computations
First value 0.7081761360168457
Second value 0.6579079627990723
Running as a single computation
Both values 37.74176549911499
```

Is there a common pattern for solving this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

Import and run the following and things should be faster

```
from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client()
```

Make sure you have dask.distributed installed

```
conda install dask distributed -c conda-forge
# or 
pip install dask distributed --upgrade
```

Although note, you'll have to do this within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block at the bottom of the file rather than at the top level:

```
from ... import ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Client()
    # proceed with the rest of your dask.bag code
```

#### Long answer

Dask has a variety of schedulers.  Dask.bag uses the multiprocessing scheduler by default, but could use others just as easily.  See [this doc](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html) for more information.

The multiprocessing scheduler does work in a separate process, and then it brings those results back to the main process when necessary.  For simple linear workloads like `b.map(...).filter(...).frequencies()` tasks can all be fused into one single task that goes to a process, computes, and then returns just a very small result.

However, when a workload has any sort of forking (such as you describe) the multiprocessing scheduler has to send the data back to the main process.  Depending on the data, this can be expensive because we need to serialize the objects as they move between processes.  The basic multiprocessing scheduler within Dask has no concept of data locality.  Everything is coordinated by the central process.

Fortunately, [Dask's distributed scheduler](https://distributed.readthedocs.org) is much smarter and can handle these situations easily.  When you run `dask.distributed.Client()` without any arguments you create a local "cluster" of processes on your computer.  There are a variety of other advantages to this; for example if you navigate to https://localhost:8787/status you'll be treated to a running [dashboard](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web.html) of all of your computations.